# Can't get location on device in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7

I use [SwiftLocation](https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftLocation)

When I run on simulator - everything is ok.

When run on device, after 10 second get - "Timeout reached" in log

I already add NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription and NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription to Info.plist

How to fixed it?

Thanks.

p.s. my code:

```
    try! SwiftLocation.shared.currentLocation(Accuracy.Room, timeout: 20, onSuccess: { (location) -> Void in
        // location is a CLPlacemark
        print("1. Location found \(location?.description)")
        }) { (error) -> Void in
            print("1. Something went wrong -> \(error?.localizedDescription)")
    }
```

Comment: Please add your code where you actually try to get the location

Comment: @mihirmehta done. I also see pointer location, when code try to get location...

Answer (score 0):

Please your code run in device and location services on , not run simulator